# Active Admin and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

**Update:**
I think I finally solved it.. I had the following code in my Active Admin Initializer file:

```
  module ActiveAdmin
    class BaseController
      with_role :admin
    end
  end
```

Removing this piece of code seems to fix the problem.

I'm setting up a new Rails 4 app, where I've just installed Active Admin on (gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin').

I can create new records from the rails console, but whenever I try to create a new record or update one within Active Admin I get the following error, which I can't seem to get my head around. Anyone who can point me in the right direction.

```
12:06:59 web.1     | Started GET "/admin/teams/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-31 12:06:59 +0100
12:06:59 web.1     | Processing by Admin::TeamsController#new as HTML
12:06:59 web.1     |   AdminUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
12:06:59 web.1     | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
12:06:59 web.1     | 
12:06:59 web.1     | ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)):
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:180:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/KennethSkou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@Todo/bundler/gems/active_admin-0f663e3ad728/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:142:in `build_new_resource'
/Users/KennethSkou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@Todo/bundler/gems/active_admin-0f663e3ad728/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:129:in `build_resource'
inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:19:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__3851194588154266790__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__307601885218201832__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My App/Admin/Team.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Team do

  def permitted_params
    params.permit!
  end

end
```

Comment: please, attach code from app/admin/teams.rb, did you add ```permitted_params``` method there?

Comment: Hi.. just updated my post with it.

Comment: was struggling too with this and thanks to you was reminded of what i had put in my initalizer. thanks! this was the root of my bug